# Advanced PHP loop

Tags: php, nested-loops

I get translations from database and want to get generate it in Javascript object, like:

```
var Lang = {
  eng: {
    txtUserName: 'Username',
    txtLogout: 'Logout'
  },
  dnk: {
    txtUserName: 'Brugernavn',
    txtLogout: 'Afslut'
  }
}
```

I got stuck in loops, the result I get is not what I need.
This is my PHP:

```
var Lang = {
    <?php
      $allLangs = $this->params->getLanguages;
      foreach ($allLangs as $allLang) :
        echo $allLang->lang_code . ': ';
        echo '{';
        foreach ( $translationsall as $translation ) :
            if ( $translation['it_text'] == 'txtUserName' ) :
              for ( $i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++ ){
                    var_dump($translationsall[$i]);
              }
            endif;
        endforeach;
        echo '},';
        echo "\r\n";
        endforeach;
    ?>
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
var Lang = {
  dnk: {array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(8) "appTitle"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(3) "VMS"
  }
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(8) "appTitle"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(3) "VMS"
  }
},
eng: {array(2) {
  ["it_text"]=>
  string(8) "appTitle"
  ["it_name"]=>
  string(3) "VMS"
}
array(2) {
  ["it_text"]=>
  string(8) "appTitle"
  ["it_name"]=>
  string(3) "VMS"
}
}
```

How can I edit my loops to get result I need?

Maybe there is a smarter way to generate Lang object?

And, forgot to mention that I need only few translations, that's why I have this in PHP if:

```
if ( $translation['it_text'] == 'txtUserName' ) :
  //stuff
endif;
```

Any ideas are welcome :)

And this what I get from var_dump($translationsall):

```
array(2748) {
 [0]=>
 array(2) {
   ["it_text"]=>
   string(8) "appTitle"
   ["it_name"]=>
   string(3) "CMS"
 }
 [1]=>
 array(2) {
   ["it_text"]=>
   string(8) "appTitle"
   ["it_name"]=>
   string(3) "CMS"
 }
 [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(9) "txtLogout"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(6) "Afslut"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(9) "txtLogout"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(6) "Logout"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(10) "btnRefresh"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(9) "Hent Igen"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(10) "btnRefresh"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(7) "Refresh"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Would using `json_encode()` be a better method to build the output data structure?

Comment: One thing I don't understand is that you loop through the languages and the loop over all of the values in $translationsall.  There seems to be no link between the two - especially as your dump of $translationsall has no language indicator.

Comment: I changed query, so translation results have a lang_code, therefore I created new question. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096078/generate-js-object-with-php-loops

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't do this. - Make an API call to a PHP backend producing the data you need. - Using either out of the box functions such as `$.ajax` from jQuery or other prebuilt frameworks will help you achieve this.

If you still want to go down the line of dynamically doing this (your question) - remove `var_dump` - which is ultimately dumping the type and other details (as it should) and use `foreach` (key, value) which will help you generate what you need. - But rather going down this dodgy route I'd recommend you take a look at how to serve an API using Laravel or other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass data from **PHP** to **JS** with **JSON**.
From PHP, you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($translation);
```

And in your JS use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"key":value}');
```

You can then do:

```
<?php
$allLangs = $this->params->getLanguages;
$json = json_encode($allLangs);
?>
<script>
    var Lang = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json; ?>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with echo see bellow code :

```
var Lang = {
<?php
  $allLangs = $this->params->getLanguages;
  foreach ($allLangs as $allLang) :
    echo $allLang->lang_code . ': ';
    echo '{';
    foreach ( $translationsall as $translation ) :
        if ( $translation['it_text'] == 'txtUserName' and $translation['itl_lang_code '] == $allLang->lang_code) :
    echo "txtUserName:'".$translation['it_text']."',txtLogout:'".$translation['it_name']."' ";
          endif;
    endforeach;
       echo '}';
    echo '},';
    echo "\r\n";
    endforeach;
?>
          }
```

Comment: I tried your way, but it's same- I get `var Langasd = {
      dnk: {txtUserName':'Brugernavn' txtUserName':'Username' }},
eng: {txtUserName':'Brugernavn' txtUserName':'Username' }},
        };
`

Comment: Only danish text should in dnk:{} and only english in eng:{}

Comment: can you edit with out put of $translationsall cuz you need to use a key like this $translationsall[$allLang->lang_code] if $allLang->lang_code exist in $translationsall

Comment: var_dump($translationsall) returns all translations from database, like mentionded before: `array{[8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(9) "txtLogout"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(6) "Afslut"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(9) "txtLogout"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(6) "Logout"
  }}`

Comment: but how you separate $allLang on $translationsall cuz i dont see a key for lang

Comment: so, there are 2 records for each translation string, like btnRefresh. there's one for english and one for danish. so, I want to show first one in dnk:{} and second one in eng: {}

Comment: ok, I updated query and $translationsall returns this: `array(2748) {[8]=>
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(10) "btnRefresh"
    ["itl_lang_code"]=>
    string(3) "dnk"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(9) "Hent Igen"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(3) {
    ["it_text"]=>
    string(10) "btnRefresh"
    ["itl_lang_code"]=>
    string(3) "eng"
    ["it_name"]=>
    string(7) "Refresh"
  }}`

Answer (score 0):

As others here have already mentioned; it is a bad idea to dynamically create your javascript like this - I would instead use JSON to serialize and deserialize the data. Anyway, if you insist on dynamic creation; it'll probably be something along the lines of;

```
var Lang = {
<?php
  $allLangs = $this->params->getLanguages;
  foreach ($allLangs as $allLang) {
    echo $allLang->lang_code . ': {';
        foreach ( $translationsall as $translation ) {
            $total_words_to_translate = count($translation);
            for($i = 0; i <= $total_words_to_translate; $i++){
                if ( $translation['it_text'] == 'txtUserName' ){
                    print("txtUserName: ".$translationsall[$i]);
                }
                if ( $translation['it_text'] == 'txtLogout' ){
                    print("txtLogout: ".$translationsall[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
     echo '},';
     echo "\r\n";
    }
?> }
```

Its somewhat hard to determine the exact code when we don't know the structure / naming conventions of your database / variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var Lang = <?php
  $all_langs = $this->params->getLanguages();
  echo json_encode($all_langs);
?>;
```

Comment: var_dump($allLangs) returns this `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4188 (4) {
    ["lang_code"]=>
    string(3) "dnk"
    ["lang_text"]=>
    string(5) "Dansk"
    ["lang_invalid"]=>
    NULL
    ["lang_locale"]=>
    string(2) "da"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4189 (4) {
    ["lang_code"]=>
    string(3) "eng"
    ["lang_text"]=>
    string(7) "English"
    ["lang_invalid"]=>
    NULL
    ["lang_locale"]=>
    string(2) "en"
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how close I am with the data definitions, but I've included them so you can see what I'm assuming and hopefully be able to adjust it to your needs.

The way it works is that it starts at the beginning of `$translationsall` array and assumes that the `$allLangs` array is in the same order as the entries ( so in this case the dnk and then the eng values).  These it then populates into the output under the language key, with `it_text` as the key and `it_name` as the translation.

```
$translationsall = [["it_text" => "txtLogout", "it_name"=>"Afslut"],
    ["it_text"=> "txtLogout", "it_name"=> "Logout"],
    ["it_text" => "txtLogout2", "it_name"=>"Afslut2"],
    ["it_text"=> "txtLogout2", "it_name"=> "Logout2"]
];

$allLangs = [ (object)["lang_code"=> "dnk"], (object)["lang_code"=> "eng"] ];
$countTrans = count($translationsall);
$out = [];
$i = 0;
while( $i < $countTrans )    {
    foreach ( $allLangs as $language )  {
        $out[$language->lang_code][$translationsall[$i]["it_text"]] = $translationsall[$i]["it_name"];
        $i++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This prints out

```
{
    "dnk": {
        "txtLogout": "Afslut",
        "txtLogout2": "Afslut2"
    },
    "eng": {
        "txtLogout": "Logout",
        "txtLogout2": "Logout2"
    }
}
```